# Why does my Netbeans debugger break into a commented line of code?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, compilation

I'm debugging a Java web application running on my local Tomcat server configured through Netbeans 7.4 (also tried 7.3.1).  I'm hitting a breakpoint in my servlet and stepping through the code, but I hit a breakpoint that is commented out.

So, I'm pretty sure this isn't supposed to happen.  What could be causing this and what can I do about it?

Things I've tried:

- clean, build, and redeploy (regenerate necessary artifacts such as war, etc.)
- close and reopen both the project and Netbeans
- manually delete project "target" build directory
- install new version of Netbeans
- install new Tomcat server
- throwing an exception at the beginning of my servlet to confirm that my code isn't compiling or being served (I don't see the exception being logged by Tomcat)

Comment: It means you're not debugging the code you're seeing but an older version.

Comment: OK, what should I do about it?

Comment: Sounds like your source code and compiled code are out of sync. Try a clean and build

Comment: Yep. like @LuiggiMendoza said it appears like the version deployed isn't the version that is being debugged.

Comment: Recompile your application, generate the necessary artifacts (jar, war, etc...) from your code, redeploy it and start debugging from there.

Comment: Tried that.  (updated details in my question)

Comment: By your update, looks like you're not deploying the application in the location you're using for debugging. I would not blame the IDE nor your application. Instead, clean your tomcat installation and, without doing anything else, just try to access to your application, since it is not deployed you should receive an error. If you don't receive it, then you may wonder what are you debugging...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: can you give me any pointers on exactly how I should go about cleaning my tomcat installation?

Comment: Go to tomcat folder installation, then go into `webapps` folder and delete the war or folder with your application name.

Comment: I hate to say I'm still having trouble with this.  I have completely wiped out Tomcat and I'm still not running the code I am seeing in Netbeans when I deploy the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem ended up being related to old Java class files that were not being updated in the app's `WEB-INF` directory.

Does anyone know what could possibly be preventing these files from being updated during a clean/build/redeploy?